# when item in navigation drawer is clicked program gets terminated in android

Tags: android, arraylist, navigation-drawer, android-listfragment, menuitem-selection

In my navigation drawer I have 4 items namely

```
english,
hindi,
tamil and 
malayalam.
```

When navigation drawer is opened and when `tamil` or `malayalam` item is clicked, process gets terminated, but when `english` and `hindi` item is clicked it works. After `english`/`hindi` if we click `tamil` or `malayalam` the process works again.

I have added the menu items in a slidemenu adpater.

Comment: Post some relevant codes and your exception log

Comment: post your code. or log, so that we can see what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

No body can help in this kind of condition because there can be several reasons for that. First check whether your particular index is called properly, then check the called code. Definitely the issue will in called fragment or code which you are executing on particular index. 
Try to diagnose first, then ask for help.